# replacing Result's html

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have an URL which shows me a coupon form based on id:

> GET         /coupon/:couponId

All the coupon forms are different and submit different POST params to:

> POST        /saveCoupon/:id

I want to have a convenient way of debugging my coupons and be able to have a way of viewing actual POST params submitted.

I've made a controller on URL `POST /outputPOST/saveCoupon/:id` which saves nothing, but prints to browser POST params received.

Now I want to have an URL like `GET /changeActionUrl/coupon/:couponId` which calls `GET /coupon/:couponId` and then substitutes form's action URL `POST /saveCoupon/:id` with `POST /outputPOST/saveCoupon/:id` .

In other words I want to do something like:

```
Result.getHtml().replace("/saveCoupon/","/outputPOST/saveCoupon/");
```

With this I can easily debug my coupons just by adding "/outputPOST" in the browser.

Comment: Why not just use developer tools in your browser? (Chrome: open Developer Tools/Network, then post. You will see Form Data).

Comment: Because it's not what I want. Imagine that instead of simply printing POST params I would also like to check that something exists in DB and print based on this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a bookmarklet and javascript to replace all of the forms' action attributes. That way your developer can do it with one click instead of changing urls.

Something like this will prefix all form actions on the page with "/outputPOST".

```
javascript:(function(){var forms=document.getElementsByTagName('FORM');for(i=0;i<forms.length;++i){forms[i].setAttribute('action','/outputPOST'+forms[i].getAttribute('action'));}})();
```

Comment: Wow! What an elegant way!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, at least not everything ;)

In general you can debug every piece of Play app using debugger ([check for your favorite IDE tips how to do that](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE))  - this will be always better, faster, etc etc, than modifying code only for checking incoming values.

I.e. Idea 13+ with Play support allows for debbuging like a dream!

Comment: I was using "debug" in a wrong context. I want higher level debug. I have a front-end developer who works on views without touching controllers. I want to give him a way of looking at what he actually POSTs to the server just by adding "/changeActionUrl/" to the coupon's URL.

Comment: But your Result is just rendered view right ? something like `return ok(myView.render(param))` and you want to modify it ?

Comment: Right! But without touching original controller. I just want to build "debug" wrapper-controller which replaces some strings in the Result from wrapped controller.